# Как проверить, является ли элемент на странице скроллируемым?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть элементы `div` со значением `overflow:scroll`. При загрузке страницы некоторые элементы получают ползунок прокрутки, некоторые нет, в зависимости от содержимого. Как сразу после загрузки страницы проверить, какие элементы являются скроллируемыми, а какие нет, используя JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки содержимого можно использовать свойства `scrollHeight` и `clientHeight`. Если элемент не скроллируемый, то `scrollHeight <= clientHeight`.

Answer (score 2):

если я правильно понял вопрос, вам надо сравнить значения `element.offsetHeight` и `element.scrollHeight` - если они равны, то скролл не появился

Comment: Свойство offsetHeight возвращает высоту клиентской области элемента страницы учитывая отступы, границы и полосы прокрутки. Поэтому его значение может быть больше, чем реальный вмещаемый контент и полосы прокрутки появятся не смотря на меньший размер. Поэтому надо использовать clientHeight.

Comment: да, вы правы. ваш вариант более корректный